# How to disable a button when the form is invalid?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a custom element that basically contains an email and password form,

Is there any way to disable the button when the email or the password are not filled ?

Please find below my element:

```
      <paper-dialog id="dialog">
    <h2>Login</h2>

      <paper-input id="zumbuza" type="email" is="iron-input" label="Email" type="text" bind-value="{{user.email}}" auto-validate  error-message="Auto v"></paper-input>


    <paper-input-container>
       <label>Passwrod</label>
       <input  is="iron-input" type="password" bind-value="{{user.password}}"></input>
    </paper-input-container>

    <paper-button toggles raised active class="colorful">Submit</paper-button>

  </paper-dialog>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I know of for validation is a form. Polymer has a custom element called 'iron-form'. There's a demo on it on: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-form?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=iron-form

The code below is a straight copy paste from there. Have a look at that and I think you'll figure it out.

```
<form is="iron-form" method="get" action="/" id="eventsDemo">
  <paper-input name="name" label="Name" required auto-validate></paper-input>
  <paper-input name="password" label="Password" type="password" required auto-validate></paper-input>
  <paper-checkbox name="read" required>You must check this box</paper-checkbox><br>
  <paper-button raised onclick="_delayedSubmit(event)" disabled id="eventsDemoSubmit">
    <paper-spinner id="spinner" hidden></paper-spinner>Submit</paper-button>
  <paper-button raised onclick="_reset(event)">Reset</paper-button>
  <div class="output"></div>
</form>
<script>
  eventsDemo.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    // Validate the entire form to see if we should enable the `Submit` button.
    eventsDemoSubmit.disabled = !eventsDemo.validate();
  });
  function _delayedSubmit(event) {
    spinner.active = true;
    spinner.hidden = false;
    eventsDemoSubmit.disabled = true;
    // Simulate a slow server response.
    setTimeout(function() {
      Polymer.dom(event).localTarget.parentElement.submit();
    }, 1000);
  }
  function _reset(event) {
    var form = Polymer.dom(event).localTarget.parentElement
    form.reset();
    form.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = '';
  }
  document.getElementById('eventsDemo').addEventListener('iron-form-submit', function(event) {
    spinner.active = false;
    spinner.hidden = true;
    eventsDemoSubmit.disabled = false;
    this.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(event.detail);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much this was surely helpful and solved my issue !

Comment: Not a problem! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using js

```
    $(".submit-name").attr("disabled", "true");
    $(".control-name").blur(function(){
        if ($(this).val() != "") {
            $(".submit-name").removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            $(".submit-name").attr("disabled", "true");        
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi Rishabh, Actually js sounds fine if it is only one input field, as the number of inputs grows there will be a large ammount of code to be written

Comment: You write a function which takes in a field name as input and checks whether they are valid or not call that function for every field and enable the button when all pass or else keep the button disabled